# Fluent Validation not working on Exception

Tags: servicestack, fluentvalidation

After upgrading ServiceStack to 4.5.8, ServiceStack eats the exception thrown by Fluent Validation and passes validation instead of failing it whenever an exception is thrown inside the validator.  This appears to only happen when the validator being run is using the SetValidator method.

This will return the new user instead of returning an error message "Validator Exception".

Validator

```
public class SaveUserValidator : AbstractValidator<SaveUser>
{
    public SaveUserValidator()
    {
        this.CascadeMode = CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure;

        RuleFor(x => x.Id)
            .Must(ThrowException);

        RuleFor(x => x.User)
            .SetValidator(new UserValidator());
    }

    private bool ThrowException(int arg)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Validator Exception");
    }
}
```

UserValidator

```
public class UserValidator : AbstractValidator<User>
{
    public UserValidator()
    {
        this.CascadeMode = CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure;

        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty();
    }
}
```

User

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

SaveUser

```
public class SaveUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

UserService

```
public class UserService : Service
{
    public IHttpResult Post(SaveUser request)
    {
        return new HttpResult(new SaveUser { Id = -100, User = new User { Name = "bad name" } }, HttpStatusCode.Created);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack upgraded to use the [latest version of FluentValidation](http://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v4.5.8#fluent-validation-upgraded) in v4.5.8, one of the changes outlined in the Release Notes that changed with Fluent Validation since the previus version was having to explicitly specify properties that should not be null, so your UserValidator should change to:

```
RuleFor(x => x.User)
    .NotEmpty()
    .SetValidator(new UserValidator());
```

The issue with the swallowed Exception was due to `ChildValidatorAdaptor` being made async and Exceptions thrown were not handled as Validation Exceptions like `Must()` are supposed to return a `boolean` if the property validation has failed, e.g:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Id)
    .Must(id => false);
```

Not throw an Exception, but I've just added support for handling Exceptions thrown in validators in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/e1c82716981f86d609b64ce6297f37fdd6bf502e). This change is available from v4.5.13 that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: Awesome response time!  Ideally we'll develop code that will not throw an exception, but in the rare (or not so rare) chance that it does, thank you!